# Ubuntu 18.04.5 occasionally freezing due to linux-image-5.4.0-47-generic

Tags: 18.04, kernel, freeze, crash

Over the past month, Ubuntu 18.04 occasionally freezes. My mouse will be free but I can't click on anything or even use Alt+F2 for a command. I usually follow [these directions](https://askubuntu.com/a/36717/1017437) to restart my system with the REISUB method (and I've also changed the permissions the way the user described). Whenever I rebooted the system I didn't look at the crash report but today I opened `var/crash` and found `linux-image-5.4.0-47-generic.34291.crash` that contained the following:

```
ProblemType: KernelOops
Annotation: Your system might become unstable now and might need to be restarted.
Date: Mon Sep 28 00:07:01 2020
Failure: oops
OopsText:
 BUG: Bad page map in process pool  pte:00080114 pmd:428695067
 addr:00007fc48bc23000 vm_flags:08000070 anon_vma:0000000000000000 mapping:ffff94288e38ba08 index:e3
 file:libXdamage.so.1.1.0 fault:ext4_filemap_fault mmap:ext4_file_mmap readpage:ext4_readpage
 CPU: 5 PID: 27665 Comm: pool Tainted: P    B      OE     5.4.0-47-generic #51~18.04.1-Ubuntu
 Hardware name: To be filled by O.E.M. To be filled by O.E.M./M5A97 R2.0, BIOS 1602 02/25/2013
 Call Trace:

Package: linux-image-5.4.0-47-generic 5.4.0-47.51~18.04.1
SourcePackage: linux
Tags: kernel-oops
Uname: Linux 5.4.0-47-generic x86_64
```

```
$ uname -a
$ Linux computername 5.4.0-48-generic #52~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep 10 12:50:22 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.5.

I'm not sure where to go from here so any help in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'd suggest filing that crash report via `ubuntu-bug /var/crash/linux-image-5.4.0-47-generic.34291.crash` . You can refer to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs for more details.

Comment: I've done a clean install because the crashes were becoming worse. I still have the crash report. But it looks like `ubuntu-bug` logs local system information. Is there any way I can still log this? Fwiw, I always reported the bug through the gui pop-up.